# Send string to a tcp socket using GapSocket

Tags: ios, sockets, cordova

I am trying to establish a socket connection using [GapSocket](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/GapSocket) and send some data (strings) to a tcp socket from an PhoneGap to a computer with port 8888 open. I have included all dependencies:

1. Both asyncsocket.m and asynsocket.h from [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/)
2. Both GapSocketCommand.m and GapSocketCommand.h from GapSocket
3. Included GapSocket.js and referenced the js file from index.html under www folder.

Following is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            var mySocket = new GapSocket(127.0.0.1, 8888);
            mySocket.onopen = function(){ alert("Socket opened."); };
            mySocket.send("some data here");
        }, false);
     </script>
    </head>
<body>
</body>
```

It compiles okay and doesn't throw any dependency error and able to run on iOS Simulator. Before I run, I opened port 8888 on 127.0.0.1 (the machine that the Simulator runs) using:

> nc -l 127.0.0.1 8888

I can connect the open port and send data by using telnet:

> telnet 127.0.0.1 8888

with the following data send:

```
eddy-2:~ eddy$ telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
test
test
```

Coming back to the iOS Simulator, it runs but doesn't send anything out and I am not sure if I am doing the correct way of initializing the socket (I am new to both PhoneGap and Xcode). I followed steps on the readme but it doesn't provide much context.

Answer (score 3):

you need to include an entry in cordova.plist plugin with GapSocketCommand string and value

Answer (score 1):

Two things are wrong:

- First, you need to put the IP address in quotes.
- Second, you need to use the IP address of your machine running netcat (127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the simulator itself; you should be able to find out your IP address using `ifconfig` or similar).

As an example, it should look something like this:

```
var mySocket = new GapSocket("192.168.0.100", 8888);
```

Also, don't forget to register the plugin in `PhoneGap.plist`.