# use phonegap to connect two systems via telnet and exec command

Tags: android, networking, cordova, ssh, telnet

How can i connect `Phonegap Android App` to a remote system using `Telnet` and `SSH` and execute commands like `shutdown` ,etc.

Comment: I would code a API on the server via HTTPS that could intercept the commands from the phone and execute em.  I dont know if you can do it otherwise.

Comment: could you explain in detail?

Comment: I can try.  But i have to make an answer it will fill to much in an comment.

Comment: i made an answer just to demonstrate my thoughts, if you can use my idea please remember https.

Comment: ok thankyou, you had given me some lead, i will try it

Comment: Maybe you could also try and look for some native plugin written for phonegap usage, that has the ability to do what you want.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first say that this is merely a template to explain my thoughts.  Remember that HTTPS would be a must to do this.

Setting up HTTPS on your webserver is the thing u need to do.

**On the server**

You can place a php file called cmd.php.

In that file you could do something like:

```
<?php

    if( get_the_argument_from_the_url_request ) {
        if (argument == "telnet") {
            // do your stuff
            exec("telnet ...");

        } else if( ... ) {
            // do your stuff
            exec("ssh ...");

        } else... // and so forth
    }

?>
```

**On the phone**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.yourwebsite.com/?telnet=some_command",
    success:function(data){
        // success code here
    }
});
```

If you want some sort of response form the server you can invoke a php script as a job when the server is rebooted.

You could create a database that the app itself and the server could write to, in order to create success/error messages.

There are ofc other solutions, but to put the idea on the table here it is.

I hope that i was of some sort of help. :)

Comment: i cannot place cmd.php on server side, as the App need to connect different system according to user and execute the command .

Comment: sorry i misunderstood your answer, now i got it

Comment: look here, this might be something for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747848/send-string-to-a-tcp-socket-using-gapsocket

Comment: Ya,that kind stuff only i am trying to do in android.

Comment: Im afraid that there aint none official module for android to do this as we talk.  there might be some private github thing that someone created.  :)

Comment: yes correct it is available IOS and not for Android, i just now found one private github plugin and trying to use it

Answer (score 0):

[sockets-for-cordova](https://github.com/blocshop/sockets-for-cordova)

> This Cordova plugin provides JavaScript API, that allows you to
>   communicate with server through TCP protocol.
>
> Currently we support these platforms: iOS, Android, WP8.